# json array is repeating index

Tags: php, json

this is my code :

```
if ($API->connect("192.168.81.130", "admin", "")) {
    $API->write('/ip/route/print', false);
    $API->write('=.proplist=.id', false);
    $API->write('=.proplist=dst-address', false);
    $API->write('=.proplist=pref-src', false);
    $API->write('=.proplist=gateway');
    $result = $API->read();
    $API->disconnect();

    foreach ($result as $route){
        $response['id'] = $route['.id'];
        $response['dst-address'] = $route['dst-address'];
        if (isset($route['pref-src'])) {
            $response['pref-src'] = $route['pref-src'];
        } else {
            $response['pref-src'] = "";
        }
        $response['gateway'] = $route['gateway'];
        $array[] = $response;
        echo json_encode($array);
    } 
}
```

and the output is :

```
[{"id":"*2","dst-address":"0.0.0.0\/0","pref-src":"","gateway":"192.168.1.1"}][{"id":"*2","dst-address":"0.0.0.0\/0","pref-src":"","gateway":"192.168.1.1"},{"id":"*420639B3","dst-address":"192.168.81.0\/24","pref-src":"192.168.81.130","gateway":"ether1"}]
```

result for "[{"id":"*2","dst-address":"0.0.0.0/0","pref-src":"","gateway":"192.168.1.1"}]" is show twice.

i want the out put like this :

```
> [{"id":"*2","dst-address":"0.0.0.0\/0","pref-src":"","gateway":"192.168.1.1"},{"id":"*420639B3","dst-address":"192.168.81.0\/24","pref-src":"192.168.81.130","gateway":"ether1"}].
```

can anyone help me?.

Comment: Your first output has a syntax error, is this by design?

Comment: Also, why not just do `json_encode(array_unique($array))`? This will get rid of all duplicates.

Comment: it's shows error "array to string conversion" @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your array each time round the loop otherwise you are just adding to it each time, hence the duplication

You also need to move the echo of the json string to outside the loop

```
foreach ($result as $route){
    $response = array();

    $response['id'] = $route['.id'];
    $response['dst-address'] = $route['dst-address'];
    if (isset($route['pref-src'])) {
        $response['pref-src'] = $route['pref-src'];
    } else {
        $response['pref-src'] = "";
    }
    $response['gateway'] = $route['gateway'];
    $array[] = $response;

} 
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly it works when I move the echo and Initialize array to outsite the loop.